# SqlServer - Specify a code page on data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, codepages

Data come from ODBC. The code page is different between the SqlServer database and the ODBC data.

The ODBC data don't specify the original code page and SqlServer interpret as him default code page.

Version :
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)

For example :

```
SELECT cast(cast('é' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 as varbinary(10)) as varchar(10))
```

returns ','

```
SELECT cast(cast('é' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as varbinary(10)) as varchar(10))
```

returns 'é'

### How can I specify the original code page in the query?

Edit :
nvarchar don't work, the result is empty string.

```
SELECT cast(cast('é' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 as varbinary(10)) as nvarchar(10))
```

re-Edit :
Specify nvarchar in the ODBC query :

```
select Reference from openrowset('MSDASQL', 'Dsn=***', 'SELECT cast(Reference as nvarchar) as Reference FROM Orders') as tmp
```

This query return the error message :

```
 [ODBC Engine Interface]Invalid column type: nvarchar.
```

Comment: Why you use varchar? Try use nvarchar and unicode

Comment: codepage for non-unicode data can be set for windows user

Comment: Set for Windows user will be big break change. I want specify only on some ODBC column. I search a keyword to SqlServer interpret this column as CP850. COLLATE can convert, but nothing to interpret.

Comment: Can I set code page for a Sql User? If yes, I can create a Sql User with this code page and execute my query with this user. Can you explain how?

Comment: Is it impossible to use nvarchar instead of varchar? ODBC supports unicode

Comment: Thank for you help, but it don't work. The ODBC dirver used don't implement nvarchar. See my edit in the post.

Comment: Is it impossible to specify the input encodage in the SqlServer query?

Comment: What is version of second server? Probaly you can specify collation on that side?

Comment: Your ODBC query syntax is similar to T-SQL

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2. I don't undertand your last sentence (question, issue, error, ...). The syntax work with varchar (but same encodage problem) .

Comment: If both of your servers are SQL Server 2008 R2 why you need ODBC? Usually linked servers are used

Comment: I read data from ODBC Pervasive, after insert in SqlServer. A make this with one T-Sql query.

Comment: Unicode support was added in Pervasive SQL 12. If you can update, many problems may disappear...

Comment: What I need update? SqlServer? The driver ODBC Pervasive?

Comment: `SELECT cast(Reference as nvarchar) as Reference FROM Orders` works good if executed on Pervasive SQL directly (without ODBC)? If no, update both Pervasive SQL and ODBC driver. If yes, update only ODBC driver

Comment: I don't have access to Pervasive SQL. If Sql Server can't translate the encodage, I will use varbinary. The client application will translate cp850 to UTF16.

Comment: We will update the tool  in the next weeks. Thank for you help.